# How do I get Min and max values to only print when "year" is entered?

Tags: java

Creating program where user can enter a month and see average temp for that month. User can enter "year" and see all months and avg temps for each month, as well as the yearly average and highest and lowest monthly average. So far I am having difficulty with the max/low average. It is printing when the month is entered and it shouldn't. I have tried to move the code around to different points but it doesn't seem to matter as it still prints when year or a month is entered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class MonthlyTemp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        //set up arrays//
        final int NUM_MONTHS = 12;                      
          int [] avgMonthTemp = new int [NUM_MONTHS];
          String [] monthName = new String[NUM_MONTHS];        
          int i = 0;
          String userMonthName ="";

          monthName[0] = "January";
          monthName[1] = "February";
          monthName[2] = "March";
          monthName[3] = "April";
          monthName[4] = "May";
          monthName[5] = "June";
          monthName[6] = "July";
          monthName[7] = "August";
          monthName[8] = "September";
          monthName[9] = "October";
          monthName[10] = "November";
          monthName[11] = "December";

          avgMonthTemp[0] = 75;
          avgMonthTemp[1] = 75;
          avgMonthTemp[2] = 79;
          avgMonthTemp[3] = 82;
          avgMonthTemp[4] = 85;
          avgMonthTemp[5] = 86;
          avgMonthTemp[6] = 90;
          avgMonthTemp[7] = 90;
          avgMonthTemp[8] = 90;
          avgMonthTemp[9] = 86;
          avgMonthTemp[10] = 81;
          avgMonthTemp[11] = 77;

          System.out.println("Enter a month or the word year: ");
          userMonthName = scnr.nextLine();


           for(i=0; i < NUM_MONTHS; i++) {
             if(userMonthName.equalsIgnoreCase("year")) {    
             System.out.println(monthName[i] + " " + avgMonthTemp[i]);
             }
           }

           for(i=0; i < NUM_MONTHS; i++) {
             if(userMonthName.equalsIgnoreCase(monthName[i])) {
                 System.out.println(monthName[i] + " " + avgMonthTemp[i]);
             }
           }
           Arrays.sort(avgMonthTemp);
           System.out.println("Minimum = " + avgMonthTemp[0]);
           System.out.println("Maximum = " + avgMonthTemp[avgMonthTemp.length-1]);  
       }
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: You don't have a guard around the max/min println statements. They'll always print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Min/Max has no `if` clause around it, so it always runs.

```
if( userMonthName.equalsIgnoreCase("year") )
{
    // User entered "year" - print out all values
    for( i=0; i < NUM_MONTHS; i++ ) 
    {
         System.out.println( monthName[i] + " " + avgMonthTemp[i] );
    }

     Arrays.sort( avgMonthTemp );
     System.out.println( "Minimum = " + avgMonthTemp[0] );
     System.out.println( "Maximum = " + avgMonthTemp[avgMonthTemp.length-1] ); 
}
else
{
    // Did the user enter a month name?  If so print just that
    for( i=0; i < NUM_MONTHS; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( userMonthName.equalsIgnoreCase( monthName[i] ) ) 
        {
             System.out.println( monthName[i] + " " + avgMonthTemp[i] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I kept putting it in the { } with the "year" statement but I think because I had the if statement after the for statement the code would not print the full list of the year.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you only want to print the max/min values if the user asks that you print the full year's averages. The issue at hand is that you haven't guarded the two println statements (for maximum/minimum) with an `if` statement, so they'll always print.

The proper way to do this, in my opinion, would be to first determine if the user has asked for the full year's data and save that to a boolean:

```
boolean requestedAll = userMonthName.equalsIgnoreCase("year");
```

Then, you can iterate and print:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_MONTHS; i++) {
    if(requestedAll || userMonthName.equalsIgnoreCase(monthName[i])) {
        System.out.println(monthName[i] + " " + avgMonthTemp[i]);
    }
}
```

And then, at the end, you can just print the maximum and minimum values if this was a yearly request:

```
if(requestedAll) {
    Arrays.sort(avgMonthTemp);
    System.out.println("Minimum = " + avgMonthTemp[0]);
    System.out.println("Maximum = " + avgMonthTemp[avgMonthTemp.length-1]); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried using a boolean but I seem to always get it backwards and everything is true and then I had it in the wrong spot too.